# React Native - How to slide cards horizontally and give them a margin

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, jsx

On the code below I'm trying to do 2 things:

- give a margin to each card with value: 20
- put the four cards in only one row and let the user slide them horizontally

Non of both things are working and the code is intended to do that.

Here is the playground so you can do your own experiments: bit.ly/2V3KbKo

https://cdn.rawgit.com/dabbott/react-native-web-player/gh-v1.10.0/

Here is the code (which you also can copy / paste on the link above):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={stylesApp.cardContainer}>
        <MyCard index="514" black text="These are the news of Monday." style={stylesApp.myCard} />
        <MyCard index="514" black text="These are the news of Tuesday." style={stylesApp.myCard} />
        <MyCard index="514" black text="These are the news of Wednesday." style={stylesApp.myCard} />
        <MyCard index="514" black text="These are the news of Thursday." style={stylesApp.myCard} />
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const stylesApp = StyleSheet.create({
  cardContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'nowrap',
    overflow: 'scroll',
  },
  myCard: {
    margin: 20,
  },
});

//------

class MyCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: props.text,
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={stylesMyCard.container}>
                <Text style={stylesMyCard.text}>{this.state.text}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const stylesMyCard = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: 80,
        minHeight: 40,
        padding: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#000',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    text: {
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 10,
    }
});
```

Any idea on how to make those 2 things work properly?

If you can, please provide a working source code.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try to use horizontal and showsHorizontalScrollIndicator props for ScrollView, so after that you can remove stylesApp